# Playing RTP using VLC

Tags: vlc, rtp, sdp

I currently have an Android application that is capturing video from the camera and streaming it over RTP. I do not use RTSP.

I have created a SDP file that describes the RTP feed. I can open the SDP file in Quicktime 7 and can see the stream, attempting to open the SDP file in VLC does not work. I get the following error:

> live555 demux error: no data received in 10s, aborting

I am monitoring the RTP packets using Wireshark and can see the packets on the network (see example below):

```
281956  2545.589171000  10.0.1.25   10.0.1.150  UDP 1442    Source port: 54405  Destination port: 51372
```

Quicktime 7 does not seem to have a problem binding to the destination port in the SDP and playing the stream but I see the following ICMP packet when attempting to use VLC:

```
286674  2925.162140000  10.0.1.150  10.0.1.25   ICMP    70  Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
```

My SDP file contains:

```
v=0
o=- 1360349812962 1360349812962 IN IP4 10.0.1.25
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 10.0.1.150
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=video 51372 RTP/AVP 96
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42c01e;sprop-parameter sets=Z0LAHukBQHsg,aM4G4g==;
```

What do I need to do to get the stream to play in VLC? I've tried using the argument '--rtp-client-port=51326' when starting VLC but it does not seem to make a difference.

**UPDATE 1**

It appears that VLC (at least the way I'm using it) does not use the client port you specify in the SDP, it always assigns it own port that it expects the RTP packets to be delivered on. I changed my approach to allow me to capture the port from VLC and start my RTP feed using that port as the destination and it worked. This is not an ideal solution.

Does any one know how to get VLC to use the destination port in the SDP file?

Comment: How are you starting VLC on the destination machine? Here is an example that worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538698/minimum-sdp-for-making-a-h264-rtp-stream

Comment: Do you have quicktime open while running VLC? It may be that both are trying to open a socket on the same port.

Answer (score 4):

VLC takes the port mentioned in the below parameter (51372) as destination port.

> m=video 51372 RTP/AVP 96

I have tried it with Audio capture.

You should just need to play that sdp file without any parameter with this SDP configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me. VLC is ignoring the port in the SDP. I'm wondering if there is a bug in the version of VLC I'm running.

Comment: @lucasweb: Ohk. just for reference - I have tested it on 2.0.2 and 2.0.5. Have you ever tried sending RTP Audio from one VLC to another VLC? (with SDP File). I am having some issues in streaming in VLC server client model. If you have tried, it would be great if I can learn from your experience..