# Minimum SDP for making a H264 RTP stream?

Tags: sip, h.264, rtp, sdp

I'm looking for an example of a minimum necessary SDP for setting up a H264 video stream.|

The assumption is that the receiver can play H264 as long as it gets the required parameters through SDP.

I have found a related document [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184)however it uses lots of optional parameters in the examples, and I'm looking for the bare required minimum.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is the bares minimum SDP. It is a file called `test.sdp` which has the following content:

```
c=IN IP4 10.5.110.117
m=video 5004 RTP/AVP 96 
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

I've started the stream on a virtual machine using VLC. (No SDP sent here)

```
vlc -vvv sample_video/big_buck_bunny_480p_h264.mov --sout
'#rtp{dst=10.5.110.117,port=5004,ttl=1}'
```

On the client side, the player was started with:

```
vlc test.sdp
```

**Update**
The reason why the stream is correctly interpreted with this minimal SDP file is that the RTP packets contain the required parameters to decode the video correctly (sprop parameters are sent in bound). This question provides a bit of conceptual insight of on those parameters [Is sprop-parameter-sets or profile-level-id the SDP parameter required to decode H264?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634476/is-sprop-parameter-sets-or-profile-level-id-the-sdp-parameter-required-to-decode)

Comment: How to build sdp file from some broadcast rtp?

Comment: Just tried it on Ubuntu 22.04, can't get video to play, but got the following server-side message: [000055b978c2b7c0] dbus interface debug: Getting property Position
How could this happen?