# modifying an existing RTP stream to play in VLC

Tags: vlc, packet, rtp

I have an incoming RTP stream on one computer (called, "server1") connected to another computer (called, "client1") over a LAN.  However, the Ethernet header (MACDA/MACSA), IPv4 header (IPDA/IPSA), and UDP header (dstport/srcport) for all of the packets belong to another network and different computers.  Furthermore, the client computer did not request or initiate the stream.  It is "just there"!  :)

I am not interested in controlling (stopping, starting, track jumping, etc.) the stream.  I just want to see and hear it in a VLC client.

I have complete control over the packets, so that I can change all of the header info as it leaves the server.

How can I modify the packets, so that VLC will play them?  I can point VLC at my server, and I can mangle the packets, so they appear to have been sourced by the server and destined for the client.  But, I do not know the destination port opened by VLC on the client.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may not have the best answer, but here's a little something that might help...

"I was trying vlc player and I says, Sdp required, cannot play rtp with dynamic payload type. Is it possible to play rtp with dynamic payload type by other player, or somehow create sdp protocol using libjitsi. Thanks a lot."

Reply:

"You need an SDP description.
I found on stackoverflow a minimal SDP description. [Minimum SDP for making a H264 RTP stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538698/minimum-sdp-for-making-a-h264-rtp-stream).
You can try to replace the IP address, port number and payload type by the ones you’re using, maybe that’ll work."