# Unable to receive RTP payload type 96 without an SDP file describing it

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg

How can I use SDP files in iOS FFmpeg? I've tried this:

```
char *url = "rtp://127.0.0.1:1234"; 
AVFormatContext *oc = NULL; 
avformat_open_input(&oc, url, NULL , NULL);
```

But I get the following error:

> [rtp @ 028568e0] Unable to receive RTP payload type 96 without an SDP file 
>       describing it.

Comment: Create the SDP file manually ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538698/minimum-sdp-for-making-a-h264-rtp-stream)) and use it as input.

Comment: I use vlc  sdp file to play is ok ,now ,I need to play in IOS App...I will try to Integrated VLC lib to my app, don't use ffmpeg only.